# Selecting objects direction from Favorite model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We have these models setup for users, categories and favorites:

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :favoritable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :favorites
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites, inverse_of: :user
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites, as: :favoritable
end
```

There are also some other objects that can be favorited (SubCategories, etc), and I would like to be able to grab the Category objects directly instead of a list of favorites:

```
@categories = @user.favorites.where(favoritable_type: "Category")
```

Is there way to grab a list of the actual Category objects through this `@user` object?

Comment: did you find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817019/rails-polymorphic-favorites-user-can-favorite-different-models

Comment: Yeah, thanks.  That was my original question, and I was using this as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just setting up a realtionship in user?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :categories, through: :favorites
end
```